# Exception: Leak detection on http-epoll-1 thread in Spring with Spring Client

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux

I got the following exception during my Spring app.
I use Spring-boot-starter 2.2.1, with spring-boot-starer-reactor-netty 2.2.1. (Reactory netty 0.9.1 in it.)

I use spring-boot-admin-starter-client 2.2.0 within my application.

It is not thrown sequentially, and I can't see any pattern on the occurrences. I've just started my application as a unix service and after some time it threw. My idea is about the Spring admin and client, but I upgraded them to the latest but the exception still exists.

**Can u give me ANY advice why is it throwing?**

This exception is happened on thread or-http-epoll-1:

```
2019-12-12 17:24:46.756+0100 ERROR 15674 --- [or-http-epoll-1] i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector
```

and on this thread everything seems alright earlier:

```
2019-12-12 17:23:16.763+0100 DEBUG 15674 --- [or-http-epoll-1] r.n.h.s.HttpServer : [id: 0x967afa3f, L:/127.0.1.1:8080 - R:/127.0.0.1:54646] Handler is being applied: org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ReactorHttpHandlerAdapter@33681b9d

2019-12-12 17:23:16.763+0100 DEBUG 15674 --- [or-http-epoll-1] o.s.w.s.a.HttpWebHandlerAdapter : [967afa3f] HTTP GET "/actuator/health"

2019-12-12 17:23:16.764+0100 DEBUG 15674 --- [or-http-epoll-1] .b.a.e.w.r.WebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping : [967afa3f] Mapped to org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.reactive.AbstractWebFluxEndpointHandlerMapping$ReadOperationHandler@6de54b40

2019-12-12 17:23:17.768+0100 DEBUG 15674 --- [or-http-epoll-1] r.n.h.s.HttpServerOperations : [id: 0x967afa3f, L:/127.0.1.1:8080 - R:/127.0.0.1:54646] Decreasing pending responses, now 0

2019-12-12 17:23:17.768+0100 DEBUG 15674 --- [or-http-epoll-1] o.s.w.s.a.HttpWebHandlerAdapter : [967afa3f] Completed 200 OK

2019-12-12 17:23:17.768+0100 DEBUG 15674 --- [or-http-epoll-1] r.n.h.s.HttpServerOperations : [id: 0x967afa3f, L:/127.0.1.1:8080 - R:/127.0.0.1:54646] Last HTTP response frame

2019-12-12 17:23:17.768+0100 DEBUG 15674 --- [or-http-epoll-1] r.n.h.s.HttpServerOperations : [id: 0x967afa3f, L:/127.0.1.1:8080 - R:/127.0.0.1:54646] Last HTTP packet was sent, terminating the channel

2019-12-12 17:24:17.959+0100 DEBUG 15674 --- [or-http-epoll-1] r.n.h.s.HttpServerOperations : [id: 0x967afa3f, L:/127.0.1.1:8080 - R:/127.0.0.1:54646] Decreasing pending responses, now 0

2019-12-12 17:24:17.959+0100 DEBUG 15674 --- [or-http-epoll-1] r.n.h.s.HttpServerOperations : [id: 0x967afa3f, L:/127.0.1.1:8080 - R:/127.0.0.1:54646] Last HTTP packet was sent, terminating the channel

2019-12-12 17:24:46.756+0100 ERROR 15674 --- [or-http-epoll-1] i.n.u.ResourceLeakDetector : LEAK: ByteBuf.release() was not called before it's garbage-collected. See https://netty.i o/wiki/reference-counted-objects.html for more information. 
Recent access records: 
Created at:
    #011io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:349)
    #011io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:187)
    #011io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:178)
    #011io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:115)
    #011io.netty.buffer.ByteBufUtil.readBytes(ByteBufUtil.java:445) #011io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocket08FrameDecoder.decode(WebSocket08FrameDecoder.java:314)
    #011io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:503)
    #011io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442)
    #011io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:281)
    #011io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    #011io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    #011io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:352)
    #011io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1422)
    #011io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:374)
    #011io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:360)
    #011io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:931)
    #011io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792)
    #011io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:502)
    #011io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:407) #011io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$6.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:1050)
    #011io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    #011io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    #011java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: For readability's sake, consider having the log output/exception in a block, using for example ``` stuff here ```.

Comment: Edited and sry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: I found a message.getPayload() what was not released, i wrote that there and the problem is not occurred anymore.